# iOS: popToRootViewControllerAnimated followed by performSegue not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

In my non-root VC class I have the following `doLogout` method:

```
- (void)doLogout
{
    SDPAppDelegate *app = [self getAppDelegate];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [SSKeychain deletePasswordForService:app.productName account:[defaults stringForKey:@"EmailAddress"]];
    [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"LoggedIn"];
    [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"EmailAddress"];
    [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"Password"];

    [defaults synchronize];

    [self setToolbarItems:nil];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

And then in my root VC, in `viewWillAppear`, I have:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (![self isLoggedIn]) {
            NSLog(@"Should perform segue bro");
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSegue" sender:self];
        }
    }
}
```

This mostly works, the user is logged out and the stack is properly restored to the root controller, and the `NSLog()` call is performed, but the segue is not. Why is this and what can be done? I want to show the login VC (popped on to the root VC) if the user logs out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this code in ViewDidAppear, not viewWillAppear

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
  {
    if (![self isLoggedIn]) {
        NSLog(@"Should perform segue bro");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSegue" sender:self];
    }
   }
}
```